# How to validate business object in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, data-access-layer

I want to create a small application for inserting `Amount` `Date` `note` `Account_Name` into table `transaction`.

I don't want to create an action method for this, and want to use from CLI.

My business object looks like this:

```
    public class ExpenseBO : Controller
    {
        public void MakeExpense(MakeExpensePayload payload)
        {
            var transactionAccess = new TransactionAccessController(connection);
            transactionAccess.MakeTransaction(payload);
        }
    }
```

In access layer:

```
public void MakeTransaction(MakeExpensePayload p)
{
    connection.Insert(new { p.Amount, p.Date, p.Note });
}
```

Model MakeExpensePayload:

```
public class MakeExpensePayload
{
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I want to validate `Amount`, `Date`, `note`, `AccountName` - so for instance, `Amount` cannot be negative, `note` should not be empty (i.e., make `note` field required). The `Date` is not mandatory to provide

As I am not using action methods here, I cannot validate using model validation and data annotations.

So, where should I add validations in all these structures and how can I validate these?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you require that the form should be validated before it is sent to the server, then you need to use `Javascript` to check for the validations. If no validation is done on the client side and you get the data on the server then you have to manually check for each item and then send back the appropriate response to the client. My way would be to validate the form on the client before I post it to the server.

Comment: I want to do server-side validation here... without checking each item, is there any other to validate this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want server side validations, I consider you can do it individually. For example:

You can create a private method where you can do validations and throw an Exception to client side to inform that this field is required :

```
private void GeneralValidations(MakeExpensePayload payload)
{
    if(payload.Amount <= 0)
        //Throw new HttpException
    if(string.IsNullorEmpty(payload.Note))
        //Throw new HttpException
}
```

then, call it into your method:

```
public void MakeExpense(MakeExpensePayload payload)
{
    GeneralValidations(payload);
    var transactionAccess = new TransactionAccessController(connection);
    transactionAccess.MakeTransaction(payload);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is you should validate your data Once you receive it and before you start processing it, this will help neutralizing any possible threats

Client side validation is not enough as it can be bypassed, you should do validation also on server side

Comment: yes, that is what I need, in server-side validation, before I start using received data like Amount, How should I validate it?

Comment: data annotation will help lift some of the weight from you but if you can't use it you have to make your own custom validation classes and send custom messages to the client side app

Answer (score 0):

You can add Add `validation conditions` When you create model and use `ModelState.IsValid` to validate all models at once in service.

Model

```
public class MakeExpensePayload
    {
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Amount cannot be negative")]
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string note { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    }
```

**service**

```
private void GeneralValidations(MakeExpensePayload payload)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do your logic
        }
        return View(model);
}
```

Then you can see If any properties in model validation fails, `ModelState.IsValid` will return false.

[image]